# Do we need the testing data to evaluate the Model Performance - Regression

Tags: regression

I have been working with Classification Modelling in R and Python for the last 6 months now. With the Classification, the evaluation of the Model was based on Precision, Recall, Hamming Loss, accuracy etc., 
These classification models needed the testing data to calculate these evaluation metrics.

Is it the Same case with Regression when we calculate SSR, SSE, RMSE and other evaluation metrics.

From an R point of View - Summary(LmRegressionModel) gives these evaluation metric figures one way or another. Why do we need the testing data then to evaluate the model here in Regression.

Comment: For the same reason you need a test set in classification: because the model could be overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ML community has many more metrics than you just listed here, both for regression and classification. But the principal remains; calculating the metrics on the training set would likely lead to overfitting.